# `Gem.find_files` interacts with itself

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Suppose I have not installed a certain gem, let's say `"oj"`. If I do the following, then the gem will be installed, and `Gem.find_files` at the end returns the paths where it was installed.

```
require "open3"
name = "oj"
_, out, err, thread = Open3.popen3("sudo gem install #{name}")
thread.join
puts out.read, err.read
p Gem.find_files(name)
```

However, if I (uninstall the gem and) run the following, which has an extra line of `Gem.find_files(name)` before the occurrence of the same call at the end,

```
require "open3"
name = "oj"
if Gem.find_files(name).empty?
  _, out, err, thread = Open3.popen3("sudo gem install #{name}")
  thread.join
  puts out.read, err.read
  p Gem.find_files(name)
end
```

then `Gem.find_files` at the end returns an empty array. It seems that the first call of `Gem.find_files` (before installation) makes the second call of `Gem.find_files` (after installation) return an empty array.

- Why does it return an empty array?
- How can I fix either or two occurrences of `Gem.find_files` so that the first one (before installation) returns an empty array and the latter one (after installation) returns the included paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you call `find_files` the Gem code caches a bunch of info, including the current gem specs and their directories.

The second time you call `find_files`, the Gem code uses the same cached info, so doesn't know your new gem is added.

The solution is install your new gem, then reset the cache like this:

```
Gem::Specification.reset
```